What is the meaning of "I apply my personality in a paste"?
Here's a little bit of context from the film Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind (2004):

Clementine: It changes a lot. The color. That’s why you might not
recognize me. It’s called Blue Ruin.
Joel: Right.
Clementine: The color. Snappy name, huh?
Joel: I like it.
Clementine: Yeah. Anyway, this company makes a whole line a’ colors
with equally snappy names. Red... Red Menace, Yellow Fever, Green
Revolution. That’d be a job, comin’ up with those names.
Joel: You think there could possibly be a job like that? I mean, how
many hair colors could there be? Fifty, maybe.
Clementine: Someone’s got that job. Agent Orange! I came up with that
one. I apply my personality in a paste.
Joel: Oh, I doubt that very much.

What does it mean "I apply my personality in a paste"?

There's a little more context in the original screenplay. Clementine is bemoaning that she sometimes feels like she uses her hair colour (applied in the form of hair colouring paste) to express how she's feeling, rather than vocalising it in a more healthy, adult manner.

CLEMENTINE: Purple Haze, Pink Eraser.
JOEL: You think that could possibly be a full-time job? How many hair colors could  there be? Fifty, tops?
CLEMENTINE: (pissy) Somebody's got that job. (excited) Agent Orange! I came up with that one.  Anyway, there are endless color
possibilities and I'd be great at it.
JOEL: (mumbly) I'm sure you would.
CLEMENTINE: My writing career! Your hair written by Clementine Kruczynski.   (thought) The Tom Waits album is Rain Dogs.
JOEL: You sure? I don't know that album --
CLEMENTINE: I think. Anyway, I've tried all their colors. More than once. I'm getting too old for this. But it keeps me from having
to develop an actual personality. I apply my personality in a paste.
You?
JOEL: Oh, I doubt that's the case.

Note that this is absolutely the case. She expresses her emotionality in her hair colour throughout the film, starting with a hopeful green, flamboyant red, manic orange and depressive blue.




But, still, why "in a paste"?

@JConstantine - See edit. Hair colourant is applied in a paste.

Take all of this with a grain of salt as I've never seen the movie, but given the context of Valorum's reply above (and with the caveat of I may be giving the writers too much credit), I think the line could also be interpreted with multiple meanings where to "apply [something] with a paste" implies something very tactile and thick. Something applied this way may be hard to remove, sticky, possibly even heavy. It could also be used self-deprecatingly, where she is comparing her emotions to something trivial, commercial, superficial, and throw-away--something you could read instructions for on the back of a box.
Thematically, it was pretty snazzy writing on the part of the writer(s) to use the phrasing as they did. If the other subtext above is also true, I'd say the writer(s) did a really nice job with this scene to express multiple things with one tight line of dialogue.
